# Paypal IPN and btn_id

Tags: paypal, paypal-ipn

I am looking at a PHP script, and I noticed that the method which handles Paypal's IPN calls expects to receive the value btn_id.

But there is no such value at all. Has Paypal replaced it with something else? Maybe txn_id?

The script expects to receive the value of subscr_id, and Paypal does send it.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on the type of IPN that gets sent there will be different possible parameters on the IPN, so depending on what script you're looking at and what exactly it's doing it may or may not be handling things correctly.